# Use dataset several times

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Have a template in the ReportBuilder

> Auto Statistics
>
> AutoStatistics [stat]
>
> Auto [name]

Dataset

```
Select count(name) as stat from auto where name = @param group by name
```

It is necessary to substitute the dataset multiple times @param

For example, you want to display statistics in the brand Audi,BMW... and thus obtain a report

> Auto Statistics
>
> Auto Audi AutoStatistics 44
>
> Auto BMW AutoStatistics 30
>
> ...

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for the phrase "multi-value parameter" and it's covered off in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479196.aspx

key bit is to remember to change your dataset to support `IN (@param)` rather than `= @param`